# Facebook Link Share did not show two thumbnail options

Tags: asp.net, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, c#-4.0

I had a **`<meta name="og:image" content="imageUrl">`** which was working fine but i need to show two thumbnail images so i just added another

```
 `<meta name="og:image" content="secondImageUrl">`
```

first image was ignored and still facebook shows just one option now it's second on (Sequence of tags does not matter i checked by putting tags up and down).

Facebook linter (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) show me two correct images in og:image column.

is there any solution to this problem ??
 I need to show multiple images in thumbnail option for example i have shared a link

[image]

on facebook linter i noticed some thing called

**"The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.**"

why this happens i have provided these properties and visible in Inspect Element too and linter is also fetching correct provided images.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It resolved without any major change but just replace second image with another image of 200*200 dimension.
I had checked this before might be possible that Facebook did cache at that time that's why now it resolved himself after period of almost (20 or 24 hours).